# What will happen when Ax.Inf is replaced to its negation in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the consequences if Axiom of Infinity is negated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107639/what-are-the-consequences-if-axiom-of-infinity-is-negated)

In ZFC, if we replace Ax.Inf to such a statement that every set is finite, then does this theory satisfiable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: $V_\omega$, the set of [hereditarily finite sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set), is a model of $(\mathrm{ZFC}-\mathrm{Inf})+\lnot\mathrm{Inf}$.

Comment: You mean of course (ZFC-Inf)$+\neg$ Inf.

Comment: @Hagen: I do indeed; thanks.